# Are there situations that greatly enhance the other elements in Avatar The Last Airbender?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

In Avatar The Last Airbender a major point of the plot is Sozin's Comet, which every one hundred years passes close to the planet and greatly enhances the power of Firebending. While there are normal periodic situations when an element might be slightly enhanced (Fire is stronger when the sun is out, Water when the moon is out, etc), are there other rare situations similar to the comet during which the other three elements (Water, Air and Earth) are greatly enhanced?

Comment: There is no information about that. The comet seems to be the only one, enhancing firebinding.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thus far, the only other situations shown to increase a bender's ability are:

- The full moon strengthens waterbending.  This could arguably fall under the moon simply being out, but this is the pinnacle of that circumstance. (i.e. bloodbending can only be performed under a full moon)
- Water from the [Spirit Oasis](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Spirit_Oasis#axzz1kxZz8Zx1) has unique properties that make it a powerful waterbending tool.

The Avatar Wiki says:

> Furthermore, a Waterbender's power is strongest when he or she is situated in colder climates, during the winter, or near their native polar homelands.

I do not recall anything that explicitly demonstrates this in-show.

Comment: As far as I can recall, the Spirit Oasis is "just" a place of high spiritual power, thus enabling the Avatar to contact the spirit world. But it is not enhancing Waterbending.

Comment: @Rainer - hrm, I remember the proximity to the Moon Spirit helping waterbending.  I will remove that for now.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Proximity to the Moon Spirit may help in the same manner as the full moon itself - the Moon Spirit being an earthly embodiment of the moon.

Comment: OrigamiRobot, you may wish to add the following from the [Avatar:TLA bible](http://racebending.livejournal.com/117598.html): `Fault line energies strengthen the Earthbenders.`

Comment: god only knows what happens to waterbenders during lunar eclipses

Comment: There is also a tea which increases the Earthbender powers (strength and energy tenfold). When Aang drinks the brew, he becomes hyperactive. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A_0lfaJOMlw